# Leaving and re-entering a photo gallery doubles the amount of pictures you go through whenever you click the Previous/Next photo button. Any idea why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a photo gallery application to better understand dynamic content.

Here is the URL so you can get a better understanding:

http://claytonkinder.github.io/Day9-Project/

Here is a Codepen of it to get a better look at the code.
The next/previous arrows aren't showing due to some funky styling issues on the photo page but you can still interact with them. They're located 64px away from roughly the middle of each photo and the cursor will turn into a pointer while over them.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvjoLP

**My issue:**

Whenever you click on a single photo to view it, click on the "Go back to [Album]" button, and then click on a new photo, the Previous/Next arrows will double the amount of photos they go through. So the very first time you view a photo and go to either the next or previous photo it will go Photo 1, Photo 2, Photo 3. If you go back to view the album, click on another photo to view it, and then click on either the next or previous arrow, it will go Photo 1, Photo 3, Photo 5. After a few times of doing this, clicking the next or previous arrow will effectively do nothing and you will get stuck on the same photo.

**What I Know:**

After slapping a bunch of console.logs everywhere, I found out what seems to be going wrong, I just don't know why or how to fix it. After leaving and re-entering an album, clicking on the Next/Previous button seems to execute everything within that click event double what it did last time. I am not sure why this happens.

Here is the code that involves clicking on the Next/Previous arrows.

```
$('body').on('click', '.albumPageGalleryBlock', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
activePhoto = $(this).attr('rel');
photoPageConstructor();

$allPages.removeClass('active');
$photoPage.addClass('active');

$('body').on('click', '#photoPagePhotoBlock > div', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();


  if ($(this).hasClass('prevPhoto')) {
    // Breaks name of activePhoto into array
    if (typeof activePhoto === 'string') {
      var activePhotoArray = activePhoto.split("");
    } else if (typeof activePhoto === 'object') {
      var activePhotoArray = activePhoto.title.split("");
    }
    // console.log('Prev ActivePhotoArray: ', activePhotoArray);
    // Removes last character from activePhotoArray
    var popped = activePhotoArray.pop();
    // console.log('Prev Popped: ', popped);
    // Subtracts 1 from the number removed in the last step
    var poppedMinus = (Number(popped) - 1);
    // console.log('Prev PoppedMinus: ', poppedMinus);
    // If activePhoto is less than 1, it loops around to the end of the array, in this case it's 6.
    if (poppedMinus < 1) {
      for (var i=0; i<albums.length; i++) {
        if (activeAlbum === albums[i].title) {
          poppedMinus = albums[i].photos.length;
          // console.log('Prev PoppedMinus ChangeTo6: ', poppedMinus);
        }
      }
    }

    // Pushes the newly subtracted number onto the end of the array
    var newActivePhoto = activePhotoArray.push(poppedMinus);
    // console.log('Prev newActivePhoto: ', newActivePhoto);
    // Joins the array back into a string
    newActivePhoto = activePhotoArray.join("");
    //console.log('Prev newActivePhoto Joined: ', newActivePhoto);
    console.log('Currently Displaying Photo Title: ', newActivePhoto);
    activePhoto = newActivePhoto;
    photoPageConstructor(newActivePhoto);

  } else if ($(this).hasClass('nextPhoto')) {
    // Breaks name of activePhoto into array
    if (typeof activePhoto === 'string') {
      var activePhotoArray = activePhoto.split("");
    } else if (typeof activePhoto === 'object') {
      var activePhotoArray = activePhoto.title.split("");
    }
    // Removes last character from activePhotoArray
    var popped = activePhotoArray.pop();
    // Adds 1 from the number removed in the last step
    var poppedPlus = (Number(popped) + 1);
    // console.log('Next PoppedPlus: ', poppedPlus);
    // If activePhoto is greater than the length of the currentAlbum, it loops around to the beginning of the array.
    if (poppedPlus > albums.length) {
      for (var i=0; i<albums.length; i++) {
        if (activeAlbum === albums[i].title) {
          poppedPlus = 1;
        }
      }
    }

    // Pushes the newly subtracted number onto the end of the array
    var newActivePhoto = activePhotoArray.push(poppedPlus);
    // Joins the array back into a string
    newActivePhoto = activePhotoArray.join("");
    // console.log('Currently Displaying Photo Title: ', newActivePhoto);

    activePhoto = newActivePhoto;
    photoPageConstructor(newActivePhoto);
    // photoPagePhotoBlockConstructor(newActivePhoto);
  }
});
});
```

Here is the code that builds the individual photo page:

```
function photoPageConstructor(actPho) {
  $('#photoPage').html("");
  var constructStr = "";
  var fetchedActiveAlbum = fetchActiveAlbum();
  if (actPho !== undefined) {
    var fetchedActivePhoto = actPho;
  } else {
    var fetchedActivePhoto = fetchActivePhoto();
  }


  constructStr += '<div id="photoPageNavWrapper">';
  constructStr += '<a id="photoPageBackBlock" href="#">';
  constructStr += '<div id="photoPageBackIcon"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></div>';
  constructStr += '<div id="photoPageBackText">';
  constructStr += 'Back to ' + fetchedActiveAlbum.title;
  constructStr += '</div></a>';
  constructStr += '<div id="photoPageTitleBlock"><h1>';
  constructStr += photoPageTitleConstructor(fetchedActivePhoto);
  constructStr += '</h1></div></div>';
  constructStr += '<div id="photoPagePhotoWrapper">';
  constructStr += photoPagePhotoBlockConstructor();
  constructStr += '</div>';

  $('#photoPage').append(constructStr);

  $('#photoPageBackBlock').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    albumPageMainConstructor();
    $allPages.removeClass('active');
    $albumPage.addClass('active');
  });
}

function photoPageTitleConstructor(actTitle) {
  var constructStr = "";
  var fetchedActivePhoto = fetchActivePhoto();

  if (actTitle !== undefined) {
    if (typeof actTitle === 'object') {
      constructStr += actTitle.title;
    } else {
      constructStr += actTitle;
    }
  } else {
    constructStr += fetchedActivePhoto.title;
  }
  return constructStr;
}

function photoPagePhotoBlockConstructor(actPho) {
  $('#photoPagePhotoWrapper').html("");
  var constructStr = "";
  var fetchedActiveAlbum = fetchActiveAlbum();

  if (actPho !== undefined) {
    var fetchedActivePhoto = actPho;

    if (typeof actPho === 'string') {
      activePhoto = actPho;
    } else {
      activePhoto = actPho.title;
    }

    constructStr += '<div id="photoPagePhotoBlock" rel="';
    constructStr += activePhoto;
    constructStr += '">';
    constructStr += '<div id="prevPhoto" class="prevPhoto"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></div>';
    for (var i=0; i<fetchedActiveAlbum.photos.length; i++) {
      if (fetchedActiveAlbum.photos[i].title === activePhoto) {
        constructStr += fetchedActiveAlbum.photos[i].imageTag;
      }
    }
    constructStr += '<div id="nextPhoto" class="nextPhoto"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>';
    constructStr += '</div>';

    $('#photoPagePhotoWrapper').append(constructStr);
  } else {
    fetchedActivePhoto = fetchActivePhoto();
    constructStr += '<div id="photoPagePhotoBlock" rel="';
    constructStr += fetchedActivePhoto.title;
    constructStr += '">';
    constructStr += '<div id="prevPhoto" class="prevPhoto"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></div>';
    constructStr += fetchedActivePhoto.imageTag;
    constructStr += '<div id="nextPhoto" class="nextPhoto"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>';
    constructStr += '</div>';

     return constructStr;
  }
}
```

This code is pretty convoluted at points, as I'm mainly focusing on just getting it to work before I go back and trim it down.

Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it like 5 minutes after taking 20 minutes to get this post together. :/

Turns out all I needed to do was move that function that's called whenever I click on the Next/Prev button outside of the one that it's currently nested in.